# First homology group of a double torus (genus 2 surface) – intuition

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, intuition

First homology group of a double torus is $H_1(T^2\#T^2)=\mathbb Z^4,$ (where # stands for a [connected sum](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Connected_sum_of_manifolds)) which – for me – intuitively means there are 4 different cycles up to homotopy, the black ones. But what about those two yellow? Are they some kind of combination of the four?

[image]

Comment: The small yellow one $y$ is a sum of the two vertical black ones $b_1-b_2$, divide the latter in two parts $b_2 = a_2\cup A_2$ you should have $y = -a_2+b_1-A_2$. Equivalently this time in the homotopy group : $y^{-} \cup b_1 = b_2$

Comment: Won't the double torus be the union of two torus $(\Bbb{R^2/Z^2})_1 ,(\Bbb{R^2/Z^2})_2$ with the neighborhood of two loops identified : $(x,y)_1 = (x,y)_2$ for $|y|< 1/10$. Using $(0,0)_1,(0,0)_2$ as the basepoint of their homotopy  the homotopy group is the free group generated by $4$ elements $([0,1]\times 0)_1,(0\times[0,1])_1,([0,1]\times 0)_2,(0\times[0,1])_2$ and the homology is the abelian group generated by those $4$ elements ie. $\cong\Bbb{Z}^4$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's some pictures that show how to get the big yellow loop from the two horizontal black loops and the smaller yellow loop from the two vertical black loops.

Big yellow:

[image]

Small yellow:

[image]

Comment: I am confused. In both of these examples, we appear to be "fusing" these loops together. On doing this, do we not change the homotopy type? That is, is the homotopy type of two circular loops attached to each other the same as that of a larger circular loop?

Comment: The pinched loop and the non-pinched loop (steps 2 and 3) are homotopic. The two separated loops together are not even a loop, i.e., not a continuous map from $S^1$ to our surface. I fuse them here because the two separated loops together and the fused loop differ by a boundary in homology.

Comment: To see why a pinched loop and a non-pinched loop are homotopic (in the plane), consider the family of maps $f_t:[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{R}^2$, $t\in [0,1]$, given by $f_t(\theta) = ((t+\sin^2(\theta))\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$. For $t=0$, it is a pinched loop, and for $t>0$, a non-pinched loop. There's nothing discontinuous about pinching. In fact, these maps are smooth and vary smoothly.